# Как настроить/доработать вкладку просмотренные на сайте?

Tags: javascript, django, localstorage

Здравствуйте!
Сайт на Python(Django).
В планах было сделать вкладку просмотренные. Не зная, как  это реализовать на Django решил воспользоваться localStorage. При заходе на страницу статьи вытягиваются такие данные как текущая ссылка, src изображения статьи и ее название.
И вроде все хорошо, но в один момент я подумал, что таким способом могу однажды своими же руками вызвать ошибки. В каком случае? Например, если я удалю статью (по разный причинам), данная статья больше не существует, зато данные о ней могут храниться у пользователя в хранилище и, таким образом, такой  косяк может оставить ему "привет" в виде error 404.

Собственно вопрос. Если оставить localStorage, то как выполнять проверку существования статьи? Или может вообще есть вариант реализации данной "фичи" на Django?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

может хранить просто ID просмотренных объектов ? затем что бы отобразить список можно вызвать выборку `.filter(id__in=objects_ids)`

Comment: Либо я узко мыслю, либо это только с авторизованными пользователями выйдет)

Comment: @Jimmy авторизация не обязательна, сессию можно открывать и без нее.